# How to use references in Java?

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-reference

I want to use reference in Java but I don't know how!
for example in C++ we write:

```
void sum(int& x)
{
    ...
}
```

but in Java & sign is a compiler error!
please help me to understand references in Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference see the above post

Comment: @Esko, except you are not supposed to edit posts solely to make minor cosmetic fixes (such as correcting a typo). I find it depressing that @skaffman posted his comment in that "tone" and that 6 more people up voted it as helpful.

Comment: @Tim: Actually I do remember reading the complete opposite of what you just said from the official blog and meta several times. As I see it, fixing typos and grammar is endorsed since sometimes it makes understanding the question itself a lot easier for others.

Comment: @Esko, you're right, but now I'm more depressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>Objects are passed by reference by default</strike> Objects are **accessed** by reference, but there is no way to create a reference to a primitive value (byte, short,int, long). You either have to create an object to wrap the integer or use a single element array.

```
public void sum(int[] i){
   i[0] = ...;
}
```

or

```
public void sum(MyInt i){
   i.value = ...;
}
public class MyInt{
   public int value; 
}
```

for your example something like the following could work

```
public int sum(int v){
   return ...;
}
```

or

```
public int sum(){
   return ...;
}
```

**Update:**

Additional/Better description of object references:

Java Objects are always accessed by a reference. Like the primitive types this reference is passed by value (e.g. copied). Since everything a programmer can access in java is passed by copying it (references, primitives) and there is no way to create a reference to a primitive type, any modification to a method parameter (references, primitives) only affects the local copy within the method. 
Objects can be modified within a method since both copies of the reference (local and other) still point to the same object instance.

example:

Modify a primitive within method, this only affects the internal copy of i and not the passed value.

```
void primitive(int i){
  i = 0;
}
```

Modify a reference within method, this only affects the internal copy of ref and not the passed value.

```
 void reference(Object ref){
    ref = new Object();//points to new Object() only within this method
 }
```

Modify an object, visible globally

```
void object(List l){
   l.add(new Object());//modifies the object instead of the reference
}
```

Both the array and MyInt above are based on the modification of an object.

Comment: "Objects are passed by reference by default" - That's wrong. Everything is pass-by-value in Java. Where it gets confusing is that **references** (non-primitive variables) are also passed **by value**. Note that passing a reference by value is not the same as passing an object by reference.

Comment: @Jesper it's not completely wrong, objects are always passed by reference in java. That the reference itself is passed by value is also true.

Comment: You cannot directly pass objects. Variables of non-primitive types are references - they are not the objects themselves, as in C++. Talking about "passing objects" is imprecise terminology when you're talking about Java.

Comment: @Jesper could you define "pass" for me, it seems that my english skills aren't up to the task.

Comment: "pass" in this context means that you use the variable as an argument in a method call. But the point is not in the word "pass", but in the fact that variables in Java are references, and do not directly represent objects, as in C++.

Answer (score 7):

An ordinary Java parameter already is closer to a C++ reference than to C++ pass-by-value or pass-by-pointer. So, all your Java methods are already like this.

*int* and other primitives are special in Java, however; the above is true for object references.

---

Edit: More precisely, as stated @fatih, all Java invocations are pass-by-value. However, when you pass an object you are passing a reference by value. So, as a first approximation, the above statement is correct: An ordinary Java parameter is more similar to a C++ reference than to C++ pass-by-value or pass-by-pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Required reading on understanding Java's Pass By Value semantics:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html
http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm
http://javachannel.net/wiki/pmwiki.php/FAQ/PassingVariables (links to several other pages)

Completely remove the notion from your head that Java can have anything passed by reference. Let's look at an example, shall we?

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        doSomethingToFoo(f1);
        System.out.println(f1.bar); //Hey guess what, f1.bar is still 0 because JAVA IS PASS BY VALUE!!!
    }

    static void doSomethingToFoo(Foo f) {
        f = new Foo();
        f.bar = 99;
    }

    static class Foo {
        int bar = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen if you remove the line that read `f = new Foo()` ? My guess is that you'll get 99 printed, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `MutableInt` class in Apache Commons will do what you want, although it's not pretty.

[MutableInt](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt.html)

```
void sum(MutableInt mx)
{
    int x = mx.getValue();
    x = ...
    mx.setValue(x);
}

...

MutableInt mx = new MutableInt(5);
sum(mx);
int result = mx.getValue();
```

Additional classes are provided for other primitive types, and also for objects.

There is some overhead involved in creating an additional object simply to provide a reference, so the solution is not optimal, but in most cases you should be ok.

In general, it is always best to find a way to return a result from a method. Unfortunately, Java only allows one value to be returned in this way.