# How Wrapper classes works

Tags: java

```
Integer x = 400;
Integer y = x;
x++;
```

At this point x is 401 and y is 400.But I think both are referring to the same object and both should be 401.
I don't know how this is happening.please help.

Comment: Title seems misleading, I think you need to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712798/how-to-use-references-in-java  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/java-integer-constant-pool

Answer (score 7):

Because `x++` is effectively the same as `x = x + 1`.  `x + 1` is a *different* `Integer` object, and `x` is updated to refer to this other object.

Comment: +1 due to auto-boxing, it might not create a new Integer, but it will be a different Integer. e.g. `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` can increase the Integer cache to 10K or 20K

Comment: pls look at my answer, it proves from different perfective.

Answer (score 2):

Opcode says everything.

```
package wrapperInteger;

public class WrapperTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer x =400;
    Integer y=x;
    x++;
    y--;


}
```

}

**OPcode:**

If you realized that x corresponds #16 and y corresponds #22. So it proves that both variables are pointing different objects.

```
Compiled from "WrapperTest.java"
public class wrapperInteger.WrapperTest extends java.lang.Object{
public wrapperInteger.WrapperTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   sipush  400
   3:   invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   6:   astore_1
   7:   aload_1
   8:   astore_2
   9:   aload_1
   10:  invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   13:  iconst_1
   14:  iadd
   15:  invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   18:  astore_1
   19:  aload_2
   20:  invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   23:  iconst_1
   24:  isub
   25:  invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   28:  astore_2
   29:  return
}
```

Comment: Thanks...can you please tel me more about opcode..what does it describe ..how to get this code

Comment: >javap -c WrapperTest.class  prints java compiled codes. Opcode is like a machine language which is executed by JVM. JVM executes this code.

Answer (score 1):

All wrapper classes in java are `immutable`.So a new `instance` of the `object` creates each time.
Of course carrying different value for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is immutable . So when you are copying some values to it it is creating a new instance of the object

Answer (score 0):

Here In this image, when you increment value of X=X+1 then it will create new reference rather then pointing to same one.So after incrementing value of X, X will point to 401.And Y will point to 400 as Y is not incremented.

[image: Check This]